# How to cancel a matplotlib callback event when new event enters event queue?

Tags: python, matplotlib, callback, event-handling

In the code below if I hover over the figure it generates, it will print "not slept" *take a couple seconds to do computation* then print "slept" and repeat until the event queue empties. What I want to happen is that during the 2 second wait if it detects a new hover position instantly cancels the sleep event and run the new hover call. or if this is not possible remove all but the very last event call and the one that it is currently working on.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

def hover(evnt):
    print('not slept')
    [i**i for i in range(10000)]
    print('slept')

f = plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
f.canvas.callbacks.connect("motion_notify_event", hover)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `time.sleep` lets the program sleep. It cannot do anything while sleeping.

Comment: hmm that was just meant to simulate long operation process in the actual program it will just be doing calculations

Comment: Yeah, but the same applies... while doing long calculations, the program cannot do anything else. Except, if you interrupt the long calculation or let it be happening in a different process or thread.

Comment: I am looking for how to cancel (interrupt) the long calculation

Comment: That's almost impossible. But of course you could split it up manually, like do the first 10%, then flush events, then do the next 10%, flush events... something like that.